# Write to hasMany relationship with Eloquent ORM/Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-4

Question about Laravel's Eloquent ORM. I've had a look on SO already, apologies if I've missed a similar question.

I have a User model, and I'm trying to write an array of Permissions back to the UserPermissions model, via the relationship in the User model.

I've setup the hasMany link already, and can retrieve the correct data from the User object (`$user->roles`), but can't work out how to write back if it is at all possible.

This is my basic user model:

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'users';

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected function roles() {

        return $this->hasMany('UserPermission');

    }

}
```

and the UserPermission model:

```
class UserPermission extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'users_permissions';

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = ['role_id', 'user_id'];

}
```

At this stage, I've reverted to saving the User, and then running `UserPermission::insert()`, which allows an array to be passed, but I'd prefer to do it in one step if possible.

Anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks!

---

**UPDATE**:

Table structure is below for your perusal:

users table

```
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id               | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | 0       | auto_increment |
| username         | varchar(255)     | NO   |     |         |                |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

users_roles table

```
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id               | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | 0       | auto_increment |
| name             | varchar(255)     | NO   |     |         |                |
| description      | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| url_access       | varchar(255)     | NO   |     |         |                |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

users_permissions table

```
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id               | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | 0       | auto_increment |
| role_id          | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     |         |                |
| user_id          | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     |         |                |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

`role_id` relates to `users_roles.id` and `user_id` relates to `users.id`

As background logic, the `users_roles` table has a `url_access` column which contains a url. If the user is assigned to that role, they have access to the subpages from that url.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by you want to "write back" on that?

Comment: I can get an array of permissions by requesting `$user->roles`. I'd like when creating a user, or updating one, to be able to push an array of data back, something like `$user->roles([['role_id' => 1], ['role_id' => 2]]);` (the user_id for the roles table would be inferred from the User object) then call `$user->save()` and have both rows in the two tables created.

Comment: So if I understand correctly you want to be able to attach different roles to a user if a user is created or updated and you want to have a row in your table for each role that is attached to the user?

Comment: Correct. I've added my database tables above if it makes visualising the data structure any easier.

Comment: At a glance, it looks like you are really trying to set up a many-to-many relationship with a solution to "bulk update/insert" relationships in the intermediate table: users_permissions. See my solution below for how I recently solved a similar problem I ran into.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not really see why you are using **hasMany** relationship instead of **belongsToMany**. Actually it seems that your database structure is already such that is utilized by the belongsToMany relationship in Laravel.

My solution:

**User.php**

```
<?php

class User extends Eloquent {  

  public function roles() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Role');
  }

  protected $table = 'users';
  protected $guarded = array('id', 'password');
}
```

**Role.php**

```
<?php

class Role extends Eloquent {

public function users()
  {
  return $this->belongsToMany('User');
  }

protected $table = 'roles';
protected $guarded = array('id');
```

}

The corresponding database tables should be: `users`, `roles` and `role_user`. These are according to Laravel's naming conventions in order to keelp things simple.

Now you may call the `sync` method and pass an array to it:

```
$user->roles()->sync(array(1, 2, 3));
```

The sync method is briefly described in the [Eloquent ORM documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#inserting-related-models).

Answer (score 1):

Okay here is what you could try.

Define a many to many relationship in **both** of the models.

```
class UserPermission extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'users_permissions';

public $timestamps = false;

protected $fillable = ['role_id', 'user_id'];

protected function users() {

    return $this->belongsToMany('User');

    }

}
```

Then, if you create a user, use laravel attach method to connect a user to a users_permission like so:

```
$user = User::find(1);

$user->roles()->attach(1);
```

Attaching the role with an ID of 1 to the user with an ID of 1.

This is how you will be able to either attach a role to a user or attach a user to a role if you are creating a user or updating one.

I really hope that this is of help to you. If not, feel free to ask me further. I have defined many to many relations just a few days ago with photos and tags so I am quite into it I would say.

Also, the laravel docs even have an example with users and roles:

http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#many-to-many

Comment: Your example uses *hasMany* relationship, which is (according to Laravel documentation) a one-to-many relationship. Not many-to-many, as you are saying. Also, `attach()` method is used to attach a single object, instead of an array of objects as the author of this question is requesting.

Answer (score 0):

From reading your question it "sounds like" you are asking the same question I ran into the other day.

I hope this helps enable to you "bulk update" the relationships while maintaining timestamps and avoiding duplicate relationships.

Maybe there is a better way. I'm sure of it. But this worked perfectly for what I was trying to accomplish.

*Warning: this is not tested code. In fact the exact solution I used myself with some search/replace to help relate to your question

```
Class User extends BaseModel {

    // [...]


    public function roles() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Role');
    }



    public function addUserRoles(Array $add_user_role_ids) {
        /**
         * Prevent Duplicate Relationships
         */
        $existing_user_role_ids = $this->roles()->lists('user_role_id');

        $add_user_role_ids      = array_diff($add_user_role_ids, $existing_user_role_ids);
        if ($add_user_role_ids == null) return false;

        $add_user_role_ids      = UserRole::whereIn('id', $add_user_role_ids)->lists('id');
        if ($add_user_role_ids == null) return false;

        /**
         * Attach (Insert into Pivot Table)
         */
        if ( count($add_user_role_ids) > 0 ) {
            $this->UserRoles()->attach($add_user_role_ids);
            // Update timestamp
            $this->touch();
        }
        // Return successfully added user role ids Array
        return $add_user_role_ids;
    }



    public function removeUserRoles(Array $user_role_ids)
    {
        $this->touch();
        $this->roles()->detach($user_role_ids);
    }

    // [...]
}
```

[Eloquent Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent)

Find me on Twitter: @ErikOnTheWeb